# Existence of linear transformation when $T:V\rightarrow V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a finite linear space and U is a subspace of V. Prove that there exists a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ when $ker(T)=U$ and $ker(T) ∩ Im(T) = \{0\}$.

What I though about that could be a solution for this problem, is to prove that a zero transformation $T(v)=0$ exists. But I am not sure about it.

Comment: Hint: Let $v_1,\dots,v_r$ be a basis of $U$ and $w_1,\dots,w_s\in V$ such that $v_1,\dots,v_r,w_1,\dots,w_s$ is a basis of $V$. Define $T$ in a suitable way on that basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $U=V$, just take
$$T(v):=0,\ \forall v\in V.$$
Then you have
$$\ker(T)=V,\quad T(V)=\{0\},\quad\ker(T)\cap T(V)=\{0\}.$$
If $U\ne V$ then $\dim U=k<n=\dim V$. Let $\mathcal{B}_U=\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ be a basis for $U$.

You can complete it and obtain a basis for $V$ with the form $\mathcal{B}_V=\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}$. Then define
$$V\ni v=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n\longrightarrow T(v):=a_{k+1}v_{k+1}+\cdots+a_nv_n\in V.$$
Clearly, so defined, $T$ is linear. Now, for any $u\in U$ you have $T(u)=0$ and for any other $v\in V$ is $T(v)\ne0$ (remember that the vectors in the basis are independent). So,
$$\ker(T)=U,\quad T(V)=\mathrm{span}\{v_{k+1},\cdots,v_n\},\quad\ker(T)\cap T(V)=\{0\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The zero transformation has $\text{ker}(T)=V$ which is in general larger than $U$.

To approach the problem, think about a decomposition $V=U\oplus W$.
(Or, equivalently, choose a basis of $U$ and extend it to a basis of $V$.)

Recall that is suffices to define a linear transformation on $U$ and $W$ (or on the basis vectors) to determine a linear transformation on $V$ uniquely.